Detect & Override redial function on long press - Bluetooth headset
I have a 3m Pelton headset that has a Bluetooth button.

Long press will trigger redial of the last dialled number. I want to override this function and assign this button press to some functionality of the app I am developing. How can I achieve this?? I do not see any intent action being triggered when the button is long pressed.


packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/acl/btm_pm.cc:270 -
BTM_SetPowerMode: Setting power mode for peer:xx:xx:xx:xx:cf:48
current_mode:immediate:sniff[2] new_mode:forced:active[0]
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/acl/btm_pm.cc:571 -
btm_pm_snd_md_req: Switching from immediate:sniff[0x02] to
immediate:active[0x00]
handleMessage: E msg.what=101
processMsg: Connected
Connected: currentDevice=XX:XX:XX:XX:CF:48, msg=STACK_EVENT:
EVENT_TYPE_DIAL_CALL[7], valInt=0, valInt2=0, valString=,
valObject=null, device=XX:XX:XX:XX:CF:48
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/acl/btm_pm.cc:685 -
btm_pm_proc_cmd_status: Clearing pending power mode link
state:immediate:pending
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/bta/dm/bta_dm_pm.cc:1090 -
bta_dm_pm_btm_status: Received unknown power mode status event:5
getLastDialledNumber, cursor.getCount is 0
processDialCall, last dial number null
handleMessage: X
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/l2cap/l2c_link.cc:906 -
l2c_link_check_send_pkts: A partial segment is being sent, cannot send
anything else
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/acl/btm_pm.cc:725 -
btm_pm_proc_mode_change: Power mode switched from immediate:pending[5]
to immediate:active[0]
bt_power: AclDataStat: 14:24:00:338 - 14:24:01:850, conn_handle: 11,
duration: 1512, acl_data_count: 3, acl_tx_data_count: 1,
acl_rx_data_count: 2, total_acl_data_count: 221
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/acl/btm_pm.cc:270 -
BTM_SetPowerMode: Setting power mode for peer:xx:xx:xx:xx:cf:48
current_mode:immediate:active[0] new_mode:forced:sniff[2]
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/acl/btm_pm.cc:571 -
btm_pm_snd_md_req: Switching from immediate:active[0x00] to
immediate:sniff[0x02]
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/acl/btm_pm.cc:685 -
btm_pm_proc_cmd_status: Clearing pending power mode link
state:immediate:pending
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/bta/dm/bta_dm_pm.cc:1090 -
bta_dm_pm_btm_status: Received unknown power mode status event:5
packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/acl/btm_pm.cc:725 -
btm_pm_proc_mode_change: Power mode switched from immediate:pending[5]
to immediate:sniff[2]

This is the log I get when I long press.

HID keyboard events are processed by the Android system itself. Have you already tried to overwrite the corresponding key events? e.g. KEYCODE_CALL

Yes! but onKeyDown() method doesn't get called. Also, I have tried declaring those two in the manifest:


But nothing catches the phone call event.
